# Simple oracle query using JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to know the order that has maximum book.price-orders.saleprice

and my query is

```
SELECT BOOKID
FROM ORDERS, BOOK 
WHERE ORDERS.BOOKID=BOOK.BOOKID 
AND PRICE-SALEPRICE =
  (SELECT MAX(PRICE-SALEPRICE)
   FROM ORDERS, BOOK
   WHERE ORDERS.BOOKID = BOOK.BOOKID);
```

don't know what is wrong with it. please help me

Comment: Please provide more information, like the error message you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is that the `bookid` reference in the `select` is ambiguous.  There are some of stylistic issues:

- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases.
- Always qualify column names so you know where they come from.

So, this might work:

```
SELECT b.BOOKID
FROM ORDERS o JOIN
     BOOK b
     ON o.BOOKID = b.BOOKID 
WHERE b.PRICE - o.SALEPRICE = (SELECT MAX(b2.PRICE - o2.SALEPRICE)
                               FROM ORDERS o2 JOIN
                                    BOOK b2
                                    ON o2.BOOKID = b2.BOOKID
                              );
```

Note:  I have qualified the column names, but I had to guess which tables they come from.  You might need to adjust the table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return a single row, you can use `... KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST OVER ... )` to find the value of the minimum of another column (without having to self-join to find the maximum value):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6dba3/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK ( BOOKID, PRICE ) AS
          SELECT 1, 4.00 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2.10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 4.20 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (BOOKID, SALEPRICE ) AS
          SELECT 1, 2.15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 7.00 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 6.99 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2.15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2.10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1.99 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 7.99 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN(b.BOOKID) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY o.SALEPRICE - b.PRICE DESC ) AS BOOKID
FROM   BOOK b
       INNER JOIN
       ORDERS o
       ON (b.BOOKID = o.BOOKID )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6dba3/1/0)**:

```
| BOOKID |
|--------|
|      3 |
```